# Why isn't Percy more powerful than this character in The Mark of Athena?

Tags: percy-jackson

Why is it, that in *The Mark of Athena*,

> Percy has limited power in Atlanta against Phorcys and his sister Keto.

Isn't Poseidon the God of ALL sea and water?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. *Poseidon* is. But Percy is only Poseidon's son, and not the god himself.

Additionally, Porky is a much older being than the Olympians, and we see many times that older = more powerful. Such as Gaea being super powerful, and the Titans being generally stronger than the gods, etc...

So - yes, Percy has strong power over water. But Porky is older than Poseidon and therefore more powerful, and Percy doesn't have his father's full powers.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple. Poseidon is the god of the sea, ocean, water, etc. He has the most power over the land than any other god of the Big Three. But, he is *not* more powerful than the primordial gods, i.e Tartarus, Gaea, Ouranos. They are much older and possess much more power than the more modern gods.

It seems that when an immortal have offspring, their powers are transferred to said offspring. It is not stated but we can assume that Zeus was in charge of fate, most likely unconsciously, before he bore the Morae (Three Fates). When Gaea gave birth to the Titans, she had more power than them. When the Titans bore the gods, the same thing happens. They inherit less power than their parents. This is why the demigods are weaker than gods and because they are half mortal, this is even more so. This is why the gods couldn't have just blasted Kronos and Gaea to oblivion.

Phorcys is the primordial god of the sea and his sister Keto is the mother of monsters. They outrank Poseidon and Percy.

Phorcys is older than Poseidon, making his power much more powerful and ancient compared to the sea gods, thus making it impossible for Percy to have more refined power over water when the primordial god is in presence. Also consider that Phorcys has a much greater advantage as he is in his home territory, surrounded by water and not to mention Keto and her sea monsters.

Answer (score 0):

1. He had a small fear of drowning for a little bit so that won't help.
2. Phorcys was the one in charge in that area so that made him stronger.

Comment: Can you [edit] in some evidence to back up your answer?